# Get a log of all the memory locations modified by a C program

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gdb, instrumentation

I need a log of all the memory locations a C program modifies during its execution.  The problem is a bit more involved than watching a region of memory using *gdb/valgrind*, because I do not have the *start* or *end* addresses for the memory region.  Basically, whenever and wherever the program does a memory update (in the form of a *push*, *move* to a memory operand, etc), I need that memory address as well as the value written at that address.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding breakpoints every time virtual memory is allocated then watch those addresses?

Comment: have you tried soldering wires to your ram chips and connecting them to a logic analyzer?

Comment: @DanZimm No.  One reason I didn't do that because I believe that using breakpoints would be slow, especially if we have a lot of memory updates.  Secondly, I don't know if the memory updates by instructions like _push_ can be captured this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can monitor memory stores, reads, contents of registers, etc. with [Pin](http://www.pintool.org/), a tool created by Intel.  Here is a [project from MIT that simulates a processor cache](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rabbah/download/cache-pintools/) (instruction and/or data).  Pin is used to create a detailed instruction trace, and the trace is then used as input to the cache simulator.

Comment: Thanks!  An example (pinatrace in /source/tools/ManualExamples) that comes bundled with the Pin library does a good part of what I want.  I can edit it easily to suit my needs.  Also, instrumentation using Pintools doesn't seem too slow, which is always a plus.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run your program under an emulator you can instrument the emulator to record the data you want.  You can find several [X86 emulators listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aX86_emulators) including Bochs and QEMU.

I can think of half a solution using `mprotect()` and a `SIGSEGV` handler:  The protected memory will generate signals when you access it.  If the handler records the address and re-enables access the faulting instruction will resume (and succeed).  I don't see how you get the segment protected again, though.

You could write your own debugger (take a look at the `ptrace()` manual page, it's not that complicated) which exists only to `PT_STEP` its way through your program.  You'd probably have to parse the instruction you paused on to determine if it's a memory access and then compute the effective address yourself (getting any necessary registers with `PT_
GETREGS`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about writing my own debugger using _ptrace_.  Eventually, I think that is what I would want to do.